# DNS Name for Salesforce IP address

Tags: integration

Can anyone help me by providing the DNS Name for the below IP address used by Salesforce

204.14.232.0/21 
96.43.144.0/20

Comment: what you want to do with the DNS name?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about usage of the nslookup tool.

Comment: It's a range of addresses, not 1 host. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nslookup tool (from the command prompt of your computer) to look up the DNS name of an IP address.

I am not going to look up all 130,976 host names for you but you'll get the idea using the first address in the first subnet you've posted.

```
Username$ nslookup 204.14.232.1
Server:     75.75.75.75
Address:    75.75.75.75#53

Non-authoritative answer:
1.232.14.204.in-addr.arpa   name = h-204-14-232-1.net.salesforce.com.
```

The DNS name of the first one is `h-204-14-232-1.net.salesforce.com.`